# update ListProperty variable after for loop kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am using a for loop to cycle the months of the year and then append them to a list rather than manually type out each month.

The variable `self.mylist` updates `mylist` perfectly fine.
When `for i in range(1,13):` is run it updates `self.mylist` perfectly fine.
But because `self.mylist` isn't called again it doesn't update `mylist` after the for loop. Or so i believe is my issue.

I think this method is necessary because ListProperty cannot be appended to but can be assigned to?
So my question is after the for loop is run how can i update `mylist` again with `self.mylist`

The kv file includes only the relevant part of the problem. Which functions as intended, to grab a value from the list and display it with `text:`

.py file

```
class Telldate(AnchorLayout):
   todayday= ObjectProperty('')
   mylist=ListProperty(['','','','','','',''])

   print(mylist)

   def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.todayday=strftime('%A')
      self.mylist= ['this', 'does','work', 'but']
      print(self.mylist)
      for i in range(1,13):
         self.mylist.append(calendar.month_name[i])
      print(self.mylist)

class PlannerApp(App):
 #  def updater(self):
      #      Clock.schedule_interval(self.monthcyclewithglobal, 0.5)      

   def build(self):
         return Telldate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PlannerApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<Telldate>:
    ---------
    -----
    --
    text:root.mylist[3]
```

Things I've tried but don't seem to work.
so I could define another function and use a return statement.

```
   def monthcycle(self):
      self.mylist= ['this', 'does','work', 'but']
      print(self.mylist)
      for i in range(1,13):
         self.mylist.append(calendar.month_name[i])
      print(self.mylist)
      return self.mylist
```

Or I could use global variables which doesn't seem to encouraged

```
   def monthcyclewithglobal():
      global mylist
      mylist= ['this', 'does','work', 'but']
      print(mylist)
      for i in range(1,13):
        mylist.append(calendar.month_name[i])
      print(mylist)
   monthcyclewithglobal() #I am aware this bit is probably terrible code
```

*Hard coding* the months in works fine. But I would like *automation*.
Like so

```
self.mylist= [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', \
                     'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

kivy V1.10.0 python V3.6.2 using IDLE  V3.6.2
Thanks for your patience!

Edit1:
For clarification this does not work.

```
   mylist=ListProperty(['','','','','','',''])
   for i in range(1,13):
     mylist.append(calendar.month_name[i])
```

as

```
AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ListProperty' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: you must provide a [mcve], what samples are a set of pieces of code that is difficult to reconstruct, you just have to try a code where we can copy, paste and execute and reproduce your error, but yours is not.

Comment: ah ok i see il make an effort copy 'paste able' piece of code soon, thanks.

Comment: **Note to future StackOverflowers:** the `kivy.properties.ListProperty` class absolutely *does* have an `append()` method under modern versions of Kivy. So, this example absolutely *does* work as advertised without modification. Calling `append()` on a `ListProperty` is standard practice throughout the Kivy community. Presumably, `ListProperty` internally proxies method calls onto the underlying `list` container encapsulated by that `ListProperty`. **tl;dr:** This just works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue with List comprehensions.
Instead of using a loop outside the variable i want to manupilate list comprehension cut down on length of the code and made updating my variables a non issue.
[I realised this while reading the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
class Telldate(AnchorLayout):
   mylist=ListProperty(['','','','','','','','','','','','',''])

   print(mylist)

   def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.mylist= [calendar.month_name[i][0:3] for i in range(1,13)]
```

Hope this helps someone someday!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this in the init method? 

Also if you're iterating over the entire calendar, you should be able to do this:

self.mylist = [calender.month_name for month_name in calender]

Comment: With the init method Im not sure really but it does seem to make life easier. And hmm that doesn't seem work but thanks for the effort!